# What is easiest way to get small copy of object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I need smaller copy of object on second layer.
I select object and press Path -> Linked Offset and resize object to smaller.
When I resize the the object I need strict 2mm between parent object and I don't know how do it.
How to get small copy of object strict smaller on 2mm?
 Thank you!

Comment: My Inkscape knowledge is nonexistent, but it sounded like you said you tried to use Offset, which should do the trick... Offset should definitely be the function you're looking for. But since you are asking the question I'm going to have to assume offset didn't work for you. How come? Maybe try looking for tutorials on how to do an offset.

Comment: Offset is working fine but it regulated by mouse and I don't know how to set STRICT  2 mm offset.

Comment: I don't think I can help with that. In Illustrator, I would just click offset and input `-2mm`. I'm not familiar with how offset works in Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape is an SVG editor, and an Inkscape SVG document is nothing more than some XML code. It's worthwhile learning about the basics of SVG/XML coding so that you can delve into that to make settings when there is no way to do it using Inkscape's user interface. E.g. in the case of dynamic offset, you click and drag the control point with your mouse to set the inset/outset. There is no dialog box to set the exact value, but you can do that by editing the XML.

Anyway, here's how to do it.

1. In Inkscape, in the file document properties (Shift+Ctrl+D), ensure the units are set to mm, and that scaling is set to 1 User Unit per mm.

[image]

2. Next, copy and then add a dynamic offset to the shape - the actual amount doesn't matter at this stage.
3. Make sure you have the shape selected.
4. Open up the XML editor (Shift+Ctrl+X), and look for the *inkscape:radius* setting, and select it.
5. In the box at the bottom right of the dialog, type -2. And hit the Set button.  That will now be set to -2 user units, and since the user units are set to mm, that equates to a 2mm inset.

[image]